# Angular patchValue of a mat-select component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

In my **Angular 7** app I'am using the component **mat-select** of angular material in a reactive form.

**The view looks like this :**

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-3" color="warn">
   <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner la boutique"
             id="libelleShop"
             [(value)]="selectedlibelleShopoValue"
             ngDefaultControl
             formControlName="libelleShop"
             (selectionChange)="onShopSelectionChanged($event)">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of shopsList"
                          [value]="shop">
                {{shop.storeName}}
            </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Md data is the following :

```
shopsList= [
{
    'edoId': '2119',
    'storeName': 'AIX LES BAINS'
  },
  {
    'edoId': '2123',
    'storeName': 'ANNEMASSE'
  },
  {
    'edoId': '2460',
    'storeName': 'ALENCON'
  },
  {
    'edoId': '2478',
    'storeName': 'Grand Evreux Carrefour'
  },
  {
    'edoId': '2632',
    'storeName': 'DESTRELAND'
  }
]
```

After the first loading , the options apperead in the select dropdown successfully, and I have a button used to force the value of the mat-select when clicked.

**I have tried this:**

```
onClick(){
    let shopObjToDisplay = {};
    shopObjToDisplay['edoId'] = '2460';
    shopObjToDisplay['storeName'] = 'ALENCON';
    this.myForm.patchValue({'libelleShop': shopObjToDisplay });
}
```

Unfortenately it seems that my data is not set.

**Any ideas??**

Comment: `this.myForm.patchValue({'libelleShop': shopObjToDisplay.storeName });`?

Comment: I think it needs to reference one of the objects of your `shopList` that you have bound to your `mat-select`. Try: `this.myForm.patchValue({'libelleShop': this.shopList[2] });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old question... you can achieve this with the `triggerValue` with mat-select and patch value.

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">

                                    <mat-select #level formControlName="level">
                                        <mat-option value="Native Speaker">Native Speaker</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option value="Highly Proficient">Highly Proficient</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option value="Very Good Command">Very Good Command</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
```

With the above, you can now get the value in the template.

```
<div *ngIf="level.triggerValue && (level.triggerValue).length; else notSpecifiedDate" class="text-muted"
                                        fxFlex="100">{{level.triggerValue}}</div>
                                    <ng-template #notSpecifiedDate>
                                        <div class="text-muted" fxFlex="100">
                                            {{'Not Specified' | translate}}
                                        </div>
                                    </ng-template>
```

Comment: whats the google Angular Material official answer? compareWith or triggerValue ? these both seem good

Comment: also, what is the new second paragraph html? how does that  merge correlate to the first paragraph html?

Comment: hi, this however does not emit the whole object, is there anyway to do that, question left here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783901/angular-mat-select-comparewith-id-number-and-emit-whole-object

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the [compareWith](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) function on your mat-select input.

Example:

```
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [formControl]="selectedCountriesControl">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>

compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

Comment: wish Google Material incorporated this in the dropdown, instead of work around, thanks for specifying this

Comment: whats the google Angular Material official answer? compareWith or triggerValue ? these both seem good

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. It is cleaner than the triggerValue version, and Angular Material exposed the compareWith input to be used for this purpose whereas the triggerValue is just a simple property.

Comment: hi, this however does not emit the whole object, is there anyway to do that, question left here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783901/angular-mat-select-comparewith-id-number-and-emit-whole-object

Answer (score -1):

Use This:-

```
    onClick(){
    let shopObjToDisplay = {};
    shopObjToDisplay['edoId'] = '2460';
    shopObjToDisplay['storeName'] = 'ALENCON';
    this.myForm.patchValue({
       libelleShop: shopObjToDisplay 
    });
   }
```