# Angular Mat Select CompareWith ID number, and Emit Whole Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Mat Select dropdown with the following values from an Object List.

```
export class Product {
    productId: number;
    productCode: string;
    productDescription: string;
}
```

The Mat select List is meant to emit the Whole object as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="productData" [compareWith]="compareProductObjects"
    <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let productItem of ProductList" [value]="productItem">
         {{productItem.productDescription}}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also have compareWith function; sometimes code and description may slightly vary depending on different erp systems in company, however ID is always the same, so we compare upon that.

```
compareProductObjects(object1:any, object2:any) {
   if (typeof object2 === 'object') {
       return object1 && object2 && object1.productId === object2.productId;
}
```

The ProductList has all the real list data.
When I patch the form, where I have product Class (with 2 being Furniture), however making Code and Description null to test.

as

```
productTest.productId = 2;
productTest.productCode = null;
productTest.productDescription = null;

 this.customer.form.patchValue({ productData: productTest});
```

Running this will patch the form, and Successfully change the dropdown item!
However, the value in output mat select from console form only shows as

```
{productData: {productId = 2}}
```

It does Not show any of Code and Description; however it successfully changed the mat select item, Without Code and Description.

How do I make it so, when patching the form with only an ID, it will change and Emit the real object in the list?

**Note:**

Have 30 other items in this form. Everything else patches perfectly, textboxes, checkboxes, trying to prevent writing special exception cases for dropdown, and want to write one fluent method for other users, if possible

```
this.customer.form.get('productData').setValue(this.ProductList.find(x=>x.id==2)
```

Comment: did u try this without null values? if not try it by providing test values and check whether all are available ?

Comment: hi @PushpikaWan yes, I tried fake/sample code and description values, they patched, however I want to obtain code and description from the list itself (the true values),  the whole purpose of this was for user to avoid having to avoid using code & description, and only rely on id number, feel free to create a stackblitz if you have working solution, thanks

Comment: It is really easy to add ur sample code in stackblitz. then anybody can try and provide solutions

Comment: set the value the whole object. e.g. if you want setValue with a productList id=2, `this.customer.form.get('productData').setValue(this.ProductList.find(x=>x.id==2))`

Comment: hi @Elisio, I forgot to annotate that I have 30 other items in this form, everything else patches perfectly, textboxes, checkboxes, trying to prevent writing special exception cases for dropdown, and want to write one fluent method for other users, if possible

Comment: @AlanSmith548 I am not able to reproduce your issue. Am I doing anything wrong? Please have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kgqvj)

Comment: hi @HirenParekh you did, when you press patch value button, the code and description become null

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 Yes, And we are getting the whole object in the valueChange. all the fields not only the productId. In the question the isssue is @AlanSmith548 is getting only id filed in valueChange `{productData: {productId = 2}} `

Comment: I would recommend you to set some valid empty values instead of null. As code and description properties are of string type so you should set it to empty string instead of null. It is one solution of all the cases and  will resolve your issue.

Comment: hi @Prince setting the code and description to blank does not resolve yet

Answer (score 0):

The formGroup does not know anything about the object. It is just passing it around in the controls. Only time the control is checking if the value send to the control matches one of items in the list options for mat-select. I think this is only place you can modify it, if you do not want to make an edge case functions.

```
compareProductObjects(object1:any, object2:any) {
  if (typeof object2 === 'object') {
    const isValue = object1 && object2 && object1.productId === object2.productId;
    if(isValue){
      Object.assign(object2, object1)
    }
    return isValue;
  }
  return false
}
```

I do not think this is idea, but if the object does not have a lot of properties, it should not be that bad.

Personally I would use:

```
this.customer.form.get('productData').patchValue(this.ProductList.find(x=>x.id==2)
```

Comment: hi I placed a notation in question, just wondering if there is More optimal/cleaner answer, I am already aware of this method, thanks

Comment: with patchValue only, I do not think it possible. Unless you extend the FormControl or mat-select.